# How to implement istream& getline (istream& in, MyString& s, char delim = '\n')?

Tags: c++, getline, istream

I'm writing a MyString class and one of the things I have to use is istream getline like in the Title. I've found several examples online with void and only 2 parameters, and my book writes that you can use this but never says how. I was wondering if anyone could help me get on the right track with this.

```
istream& getline (istream& in, MyString& s, char delim = '\n')
{
    char ch;
    s.clear();
    while (in.get(ch) && ch != delim)
        {
             s.push_back(ch);
        }
    return in;
}
```

This is what I have from what I have read, but I'm not sure what goes in the while loop, I saw push_back but we are not allowed to use that for our class, would a for loop work instead?
I have this, but it doesn't seem like getline to me and the output is wrong,

```
  istream& getline (istream& in, MyString& s, char delim ) {

  char temp[256];
  in >> temp;

  return in;
  }
```

How do I get it to read up to the delimiter

Comment: Have you actually tried what you have shown?  Are you having a particular problem with it?  Obviously, replace `push_back()` without whatever you are allowed to use, but the rest looks OK to me. Alternatively, maybe just call the standard `std::getline()` to read into a `std::string` and then copy its characters into your `MyString`.

Comment: you're not allowed to use functions of your own class ???

Comment: I'm not allowed to use the string library, only cstring, cmath, cstudio,